# Should NFS consecutive writes then reads be consistent across hosts?

Tags: linux, unix, nfs

For $work I am writing several thousand files to a directory
mounted on NFSv3. Once the process writing the files has
completed, a process on another machine starts to read them.

The problem I am having is that over 50 seconds after the first
process has terminated, the second process (on the second
machine) is unable to see the files and exits with FILE NOT
FOUND.

I believe our storage (a NAS) is broken. However I can't find a
section of the NFS spec that I can nail 3rd party storage team to
the wall with that says explicitly "In NFS, once a write is
completed on one host and the file closed the file should be
visible to all hosts".

(I accept that technically I can backoff and retry the read on
the second host, but I have always assumed that once a file is
written it is *written* from the viewpoint of all hosts)

Comment: It occurred to me that files where not appearing on another host over the NAS. But creating a subdirectory seemed to help the systems synchronize. Maybe this could help?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a workaround, I'd rather go with a backoff and retry for 10 minutes. What I'm looking for is the letter of the law about how NFS is supposed to behave, so I can see if this matches my expectation of how it should behave. If our system isn't behaving, the vendor should fix it.

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com/ is a better place to ask, what do you think?

Comment: Done: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/777515/should-nfs-consecutive-writes-then-reads-be-consistent-across-hosts